# How to redirect output to a QObject in order to print from the callback function in another thread? (Python/PyQt5)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5, output

I tried to redirect the standard output to a QtextEdit object. When the *print* call is made from a callback function that is inside another thread I get an error like this:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x235cb60), parent's thread is QThread(0x1ba96a0), current thread is QThread(0x7f0b500522f0)
```

Here is the full code of a script that reproduces this error:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
from binance.streams import ThreadedWebsocketManager

twm = ThreadedWebsocketManager()
OUTPUT_WIDGET = None
OUTPUT_APP = None


# stdout wraper for QTextEdit
class QTextOutput(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, edit):
        super().__init__()
        self.out = sys.stdout
        self.textEdit = edit

    def write(self, msg):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        text += msg
        self.textEdit.setText(text)
        max_scroll = self.textEdit.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
        self.textEdit.verticalScrollBar().setSliderPosition(max_scroll)
        OUTPUT_APP.processEvents()

    def flush(self):
        pass


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self)
        global OUTPUT_WIDGET
        OUTPUT_WIDGET = QTextOutput(self.edit)
        sys.stdout = OUTPUT_WIDGET
        self.setGeometry(500, 300, 500, 400)
        self.edit.setMinimumSize(500, 300)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText("Start printing")
        self.button.clicked.connect(start_thread)
        self.button.setGeometry(350, 300, 150, 30)


def handle_socket_message(x):
    # window.edit.append(str(x))
    print(str(x))


def start_thread():
    print("Thread starting, and you can read this (output redirection apparently successful)")
    twm.start()
    twm.start_kline_futures_socket(callback=handle_socket_message, symbol="BTCUSDT", interval="1m")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    OUTPUT_APP = app
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If you uncomment the line 45 (`# window.edit.append(str(x))`) and comment 46 (`print(str(x))`), you can see that the code works as intended, and all the socket messages are shown in the object. So the problem is not that a modification of the QObtect is called from inside a callback function, but a sloppy implementation of the output redirection. How can I do it better?

Comment: I don't know what `ThreadedWebsocketManager` is, but the fact that its name starts with "Threaded" is an important hint: whatever it does, that happens in a thread that is *not* the main one. Since UI elements are not thread safe, you cannot do that.

Comment: It is indeed another thread, but then why the "append" approach works and the stdout redirection doesn't?

Comment: Accessing the UI from another thread "can" work understand certain circumstances, but it's not reliable, most of the times doesn't really work well, in many situations can crash the whole program, and often creates side effects (including painting issues). The fact that it works for you is just coincidental, you just cannot rely on it..